# What is the verb for what iron does to a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, soft-question

Iron, or other materials, can be used as the core of an electromagnet, to get a stronger field.  What verb describes what the iron does?  I'm tempted to say that it conducts the field, but I know that's not right.

(It's not a question about the English language, as was given as a reason for closing the question; it's a question about terminology.  If it were a question about electrical current, then "conduct" would be the correct term; but it's not, it's about a magnetic field.)

(And answer anywhere you like; in the comments is fine with me.)

Comment: This question (v2) has been flagged for being more about the English language than physics so I'm closing it.

Comment: The question is not just about English. Behind the terminology is also a view of what is going on. Some people like to analyze magnetic phenomena in terms of circuits and concepts like reluctance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_circuit . I prefer to say that the field magnetizes the iron, or induces magnetization of the iron, or aligns the domains. It gives a better explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard:

- the iron *enhances* the magnetic field
- the iron *beefs up* the magnetic field
- the iron *gathers the magnetic field lines* (which is true for $B$, but not for $H$, which is why some experimentalists call $H$ the "magnetic field" and $B$ the "magnetic induction")

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I assumed that there was a precise term for the phenomenon -- most things in physics are clearly defined and named -- but it seems that I was wrong.